# Angular submit does not populate hidden input before submission

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I'm creating a way to login using different providers from angular.
I'm having an issue submitting my form, the loginProvider value is not being sent to the server.
I have a form which looks like so:

```
<form #form method="post" class="form-horizontal" [action]="loginUrl">
    <div>
        <p>
        <button ion-button block (click)="loginFrom(form, 'StripeConnect')" title="Log in using Stripe">
            Stripe Connect
        </button>
        <button ion-button block (click)="loginFrom(form, 'google')" title="Log in using Google">
            Google
        </button>
            <input type="hidden" name="provider" [value]="loginProvider">
            <input type="text" name="entryCode" placeholder="Entry Code">
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```

In my typescript file I have the following:

```
loginProvider: string
loginFrom(form, loginProvider) {
  this.loginProvider = loginProvider;
  setTimeout(() => form.submit(), 0);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just add the needed data (`provider`) to the buttons and make them submit buttons?

Comment: what do you mean? can a button have a value for submission?

Comment: Yes this should be possible: `<button type="submit" name="loginProvider" value="google">Log in using Google</button>`

Comment: But when using angular a regular form submission might not be the best decision as it causes the page to reload. A post call to the backend via the HttpClient should usually be enough to obtain a new session and log the user in.

Comment: @JakobEm If you post this as an answer I'll accept

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the different values as form values to the submit buttons like this:

```
<form #form method="post" class="form-horizontal" [action]="loginUrl">
    <div>
        <p>
        <button ion-button block type="submit" name="loginProvider" value="StripeConnect" title="Log in using Stripe">
            Stripe Connect
        </button>
        <button ion-button block type="submit" name="loginProvider" value="google" title="Log in using Google">
            Google
        </button>
            <input type="text" name="entryCode" placeholder="Entry Code">
        </p>
    </div>
</form>
```